# Basis with respect to which matrix is Similar

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a diagonal matrix that is similar to $X$ and a basis with respect to which the matrix of $X$ is similar to the diagonal matrix that you found.

Is the basis I am asked to find simply the columns of $S$ such that $X=SDS^{-1}$? (where $D$ is the diagonal matrix?) If not, how do I go about constructing this basis?

Comment: Yes: the columns of the matrix $S$ (if $S^{-1}XS=D$) represent the basis in which $X$ is written as $D$, which is exactly what you want. The columns of this matrix are also the eigenvectors of $X$.

Comment: @user137630 Thank you. If you post, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: the columns of the matrix $S$ (if $S^{−1}XS=D$, which is a rephrasing of your relation) represent the basis in which $X$ is written as $D$, which is exactly what you want. The columns of this matrix are also the eigenvectors of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct.  That is, $S$ is the matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors corresponding to the diagonal entries of $D$, which are the eigenvalues of the original matrix.